# General rewrite rule for string with multiple parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following url:
mysite.co.uk/productdetails.asp?pid=434&cid=
in this case the cid does not have a value however I do have some that do contain a value.

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCondition %{QUERY_STRING} ^productdetails.asp?pid=([0-9]+)&cid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^productdetails\.asp$ /index.php? [R=301,L]
```

as i want any string with these parameters rewritten to index.php
 If I do it like this I get a 404 error

```
The requested URL /productdetails.asp was not found on this server.
```

Any help welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QUERY_STRING` can only match query string without `REQUEST_URI`.

```
RewriteCondition %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=[0-9]+&cid=[0-9]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^productdetails\.asp$ /index.php? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: I have a similar question will start a new one. I you have time would you mind having a look?

Comment: OK sure I will try to answer that, just drop the new question link in comments here.

Comment: I have a similar question will start a new one. I you have time would you mind having a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215599/redirecting-to-different-url-with-similar-parameters-in-hatches