# Redirecting to different url with similar parameters in hatches

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect the following strings
 productdetails.asp?pid=23&cid=1
or
productdetails.asp?pid=23&cid=3
pid could be any number I have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=([0-9]+)&cid=1?
RewriteRule ^productdetails\.asp$ /Compare/Roland-Digital-Pianos? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=([0-9]+)&cid=3?
RewriteRule ^productdetails\.asp$ /Compare/Kawai-Digital-Pianos? [L,NC,R=301]
```

but for some reason when cid=3 it still rewrites to /Compare/Roland-Digital-Pianos
while i want it to go to Compare/Kawai-Digital-Pianos
Any help Welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of misplaced `?` in your rewrite condition. In regex `?` makes previous group optional which is making `1` or `3` option in your query string.

Use these rules instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=([0-9]+)&cid=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^productdetails\.asp$ /Compare/Roland-Digital-Pianos? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=([0-9]+)&cid=3(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^productdetails\.asp$ /Compare/Kawai-Digital-Pianos? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks again so much. What exactly does the (&|$) do I presume it make the cid=1 unique?

Comment: `(&|$)` is there to make sure we don't match `&cid=11` and `&cid=300` type of query strings.

Comment: If you have time would you be able to help with the following question? Thanks in advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606516/redirect-with-form-variable-doesnt-work-properly. This is a new problem for me with $_POST variables rather then $_GET