# Redirect with form variable doesn't work properly

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have on file (search.php) that uses a variable that is received as follows:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['Search'])){
    $_SESSION['Search'] = $_POST['Search'];
}
```

The form:

```
<form id="searchbox" action="/search.php" method="post">
      <input id="search" name="Search" type="text" placeholder="Search Products">

  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search" ></form>
```

so it submits to itself

I have the following redirects in place:

```
rewritecond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php? [NC]
rewriterule ^ /Search/? [R=301,L]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewriterule ^Search/?$ /search.php? [L,QSA]

rewritecond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?pageNum_RS_Search=([^\s&]+)&totalRows_RS_Search=([^\s&]+) [NC]
rewriterule ^ /Search/%2/%1? [R=301,L]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewriterule ^Search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?pageNum_RS_Search=$2&totalRows_RS_Search=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which rewrites it search.php to Search/ and the paging to Search/12/1 Which is what I want it to do.

The problem is when a search is executed the $_POST['Search'] variable is not being used. Without the redirects in place it works fine. 
Any help welcome

This is the script for the paging and Search request:

```
$maxRows_RS_Search = 7;
$pageNum_RS_Search = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_RS_Search'])) {
  $pageNum_RS_Search = $_GET['pageNum_RS_Search'];
}
$startRow_RS_Search = $pageNum_RS_Search * $maxRows_RS_Search;


$colname_RS_Search = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['Search'])) {
  $colname_RS_Search = $_SESSION['Search'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_dconn, $dconn);
$query_RS_Search = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products WHERE (Category LIKE %s OR products.Manufacturer LIKE  %s OR products.Model LIKE  %s OR products.Color LIKE  %s) AND Category!= 'Stage Pianos' AND Category!= 'Recent Pianos' AND Category!= 'Recent Keyboards' AND hidden ='no'", GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_RS_Search . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_RS_Search . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_RS_Search . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_RS_Search . "%", "text"));


$query_limit_RS_Search = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_RS_Search, $startRow_RS_Search, $maxRows_RS_Search);
$RS_Search = mysql_query($query_limit_RS_Search, $dconn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_RS_Search = mysql_fetch_assoc($RS_Search);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_RS_Search'])) {
  $totalRows_RS_Search = $_GET['totalRows_RS_Search'];
} else {
  $all_RS_Search = mysql_query($query_RS_Search);
  $totalRows_RS_Search = mysql_num_rows($all_RS_Search);
}
$totalPages_RS_Search = ceil($totalRows_RS_Search/$maxRows_RS_Search)-1;

$queryString_RS_Search = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_RS_Search") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_RS_Search") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_RS_Search = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_RS_Search = sprintf("&totalRows_RS_Search=%d%s", $totalRows_RS_Search, $queryString_RS_Search);
```

paging is triggered as follows:

```
<td><?php if ($pageNum_RS_Search > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
             <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_RS_Search=%d%s", $currentPage, 0, $queryString_RS_Search); ?>">First</a>
             <?php } // Show if not first page ?></td>
         <td><?php if ($pageNum_RS_Search > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
             <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_RS_Search=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $pageNum_RS_Search - 1), $queryString_RS_Search); ?>">Previous</a>
             <?php } // Show if not first page ?></td>
         <td><?php if ($pageNum_RS_Search < $totalPages_RS_Search) { // Show if not last page ?>
             <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_RS_Search=%d%s", $currentPage, min($totalPages_RS_Search, $pageNum_RS_Search + 1), $queryString_RS_Search); ?>">Next</a>
             <?php } // Show if not last page ?></td>
         <td><?php if ($pageNum_RS_Search < $totalPages_RS_Search) { // Show if not last page ?>
             <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_RS_Search=%d%s", $currentPage, $totalPages_RS_Search, $queryString_RS_Search); ?>">Last</a>
               <?php } // Show if not last page ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you redirect the page, you always loose the variable $_POST.

you can make your php work first and then you redirect with php function Header()

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought the $_Session would take care of that or will the redirect take place first before getting the form variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes POST content indeed gets lost when you do a redirect using `R` flag from your rules OR do a redirect from PHP.

If you want to use pretty URL in POST operation it is better to change the `action` part of your `form` like this:

```
<form id="searchbox" action="/Search" method="post">
      <input id="search" name="Search" type="text" placeholder="Search Products">

  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search" ></form>
```

Also corrected version of your rules would be this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
rewritecond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php[\s?] [NC]
rewriterule ^ /Search/? [R=301,L]

rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewriterule ^Search/?$ /search.php [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
rewritecond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?pageNum_RS_Search=([^\s&]+)&totalRows_RS_Search=([^\s&]+) [NC]
rewriterule ^ /Search/%2/%1? [R=301,L]

rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewriterule ^Search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?pageNum_RS_Search=$2&totalRows_RS_Search=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST` will skip redirect rules for `POST` requests.

Comment: Thanks again for you reply, However if I want to go to the next page it won't work the first page stays the same but the url has changed from Search to Search/.

Comment: Do you want show `/Search` or `/Search/` in browser?

Comment: Can I have /Search/ please

Comment: ok then have action in form as `<form id="searchbox" action="/Search/" method="post">`

Comment: Hija, sorry the paging still does not seem to work. The post will display a number of results, but the redirected page still does not work. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: There is no information related to `paging` in your question. I cannot solve a hidden problem. If you provide all the details related to paging, I can look into that like what URL it becomes after next page and what problem it causes, as much details as you can provide.

Comment: Sorry I have added the requested data.

Comment: You need to click on `edit` link below your question and provide this information there not in my answer :)

Comment: So what is the URL you see in browser when you click on next page?